# Open and Navigate in IE using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, excel

I'm running 64-bit excel and I need to open 32-bit IE in order for java to run on the page I'm navigating to (i'm doing this at work with some specific limitations).  I can't for the life of me figure out how to get that to work.

I've tried all the code I've found searching around but nothing seems to be working for me.  When I run the code below I'm getting an error

> activex component can't create object" error here: Set
>   objShellWindows = objShell.Windows

```
AppURL = "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
AppToRun = "iexplore -nomerge"
AboutBlankTitle = "Blank Page"
LoadingMessage = "Loading stackoverflow..."
ErrorMessage = "An error occurred while loading stackoverflow.  Please close the Internet Explorer with Blank Page and try again.  If the problem continues please contact IT."
EmptyTitle = ""

'Launch Internet Explorer in a separate process as a minimized window so we don't see the toolbars disappearing
Dim WshShell
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run AppToRun, 6

Dim objShell
Dim objShellWindows

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objShellWindows = objShell.Windows

Dim ieStarted
ieStarted = False

Dim ieError
ieError = False

Dim seconds
seconds = 0

While (Not ieStarted) And (Not ieError) And (seconds < 30)

    If (Not objShellWindows Is Nothing) Then
        Dim objIE
        Dim IE

        'For each IE object
        For Each objIE In objShellWindows

            If (Not objIE Is Nothing) Then

                If IsObject(objIE.Document) Then
                    Set IE = objIE.Document

                    'For each IE object that isn't an activex control
                    If VarType(IE) = 8 Then

                        If IE.Title = EmptyTitle Then
                            If Err.Number = 0 Then
                                IE.Write LoadingMessage

                                objIE.Toolbar = 0
                                objIE.StatusBar = 1
                                objIE.Navigate2 AppURL

                                ieStarted = True
                            Else
                                'To see the full error comment out On Error Resume Next on line 1
                                MsgBox ErrorMessage
                                Err.Clear

                                ieError = True

                                Exit For
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If

            Set IE = Nothing
            Set objIE = Nothing
        Next
    End If

    WScript.sleep 1000
    seconds = seconds + 1
Wend

Set objShellWindows = Nothing
Set objShell = Nothing

'Activate the IE window and restore it
success = WshShell.AppActivate(AboutBlankTitle)

If success Then
    WshShell.SendKeys "% r"  'restore
End If
```

Comment: Umm, why not use `Set Ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")`?

Comment: Try early binding. Add the reference of Internet explorer from Tools > References and enjoy IntelliSense.

Comment: Siddharth - intially when I was doing that it was opening the 64 bit version of IE and not the 32 bit - i need to be able to control what version of IE I'm opening.